# Search Query for WooCommerce product

Tags: php, wordpress, search, woocommerce

I have total 600 product in my website and 200 product have these type of title **'mickey' clock**. When I searching product with ***'mickey' clo*** or when search product with ***mikey' clo*** I getting search result. But when I searching ***mickey clo*** it doesn't find any products. Can you please help me to solve my problem. Following my query I using search function.

```
    if ( ! class_exists( 'Amely_Ajax_Search' ) ) {

    class Amely_Ajax_Search {

        public function __construct() {

            if ( class_exists( 'WpbakeryShortcodeParams' ) ) {
                WpbakeryShortcodeParams::addField( 'ajax-search', array( $this, 'render' ) );
            }

            add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'admin_scripts' ) );

            // VC ajax search
            add_action( 'wp_ajax_vc_ajax_search', array( $this, 'ajax_search' ) );
            add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_vc_ajax_search', array( $this, 'ajax_search' ) );
            add_filter( 'posts_where', array( $this, 'title_like_posts_where' ), 10, 2 );
        }

        function ajax_search() {

            $q        = isset( $_GET['q'] ) ? $_GET['q'] : '';
            $type     = urldecode( isset( $_GET['type'] ) ? $_GET['type'] : 'post_type' );
            $get      = urldecode( isset( $_GET['get'] ) ? $_GET['get'] : 'post' );
            $field    = urldecode( isset( $_GET['field'] ) ? $_GET['field'] : 'id' );
            $values   = explode( ',', $get );
            $post_arr = array();

            if ( $type == 'post_type' ) {
                $params = array(
                    'post_title_like'     => $q,
                    'posts_per_page'      => 10,
                    'post_type'           => $values,
                    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
                );

                $loop = new WP_Query( $params );
                if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
                    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
                        $loop->the_post();
                        $post_arr[] = array(
                            'id'   => get_the_ID(),
                            'name' => get_the_title(),
                        );
                    }
                }

                wp_reset_postdata();

            } elseif ( $type == 'taxonomy' ) {

                global $wpdb;
                $cat_id          = (int) $q;
                $q               = trim( $q );
                $post_meta_infos = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT a.term_id AS id, b.name as name, b.slug AS slug
                        FROM {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} AS a
                        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} AS b ON b.term_id = a.term_id
                        WHERE a.taxonomy = '{$get}' AND (a.term_id = '%d' OR b.slug LIKE '%%%s%%' OR b.name LIKE '%%%s%%' )", $cat_id > 0 ? $cat_id : - 1, stripslashes( $q ), stripslashes( $q ) ), ARRAY_A );

                $result = array();
                if ( is_array( $post_meta_infos ) && ! empty( $post_meta_infos ) ) {
                    foreach ( $post_meta_infos as $value ) {
                        $data         = array();
                        $data['id']   = ( $field == 'slug' ) ? $value['slug'] : $value['id'];
                        $data['name'] = esc_html__( 'Id', 'amely' ) . ': ' . $value['id'] . ( ( strlen( $value['name'] ) > 0 ) ? ' - ' . esc_html__( 'Name', 'amely' ) . ': ' . $value['name'] : '' ) . ( ( strlen( $value['slug'] ) > 0 ) ? ' - ' . esc_html__( 'Slug', 'amely' ) . ': ' . $value['slug'] : '' );
                        $result[]     = $data;
                    }
                }
            }

            wp_send_json( $result );
        }

        public function title_like_posts_where( $where, $wp_query ) {
            global $wpdb;
            if ( $post_title_like = $wp_query->get( 'post_title_like' ) ) {
                $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE \'%' . esc_sql( $wpdb->esc_like( $post_title_like ) ) . '%\'';
            }

            return $where;
        }

        public function admin_scripts() {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'amely-ajax-search', AMELY_THEME_URI . '/includes/vc-extend/vc-params/amely-ajax-search/token-input.css' );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'amely-ajax-search', AMELY_THEME_URI . '/includes/vc-extend/vc-params/amely-ajax-search/jquery.tokeninput.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), AMELY_THEME_VERSION, true );
        }

        public function render( $settings, $value ) {
            $param_name = isset( $settings['param_name'] ) ? $settings['param_name'] : '';
            $options    = isset( $settings['options'] ) ? $settings['options'] : array();
            $type       = isset( $options['type'] ) ? $options['type'] : 'post_type';
            $get        = isset( $options['get'] ) ? $options['get'] : 'post';
            $field      = isset( $options['field'] ) ? $options['field'] : 'id';
            $ajax_limit = isset( $options['ajax_limit'] ) ? $options['ajax_limit'] : 10;

            $id = uniqid( 'tokeninput-' );

            $pre_populate = '';
            if ( $value != '' ) {
                $value_items = explode( ',', $value );
                if ( $type == 'post_type' ) {
                    foreach ( $value_items as $value_item ) {
                        $value_item_info = get_post( trim( $value_item ) );
                        $pre_populate .= '{id: ' . $value_item_info->ID . ', name: "' . $value_item_info->post_title . '"},';
                    }
                } elseif ( $type == 'taxonomy' ) {
                    foreach ( $value_items as $value_item ) {
                        $value_item_info = get_term_by( $field, trim( $value_item ), $get );
                        $pre_populate .= '{id: "' . trim( $value_item ) . '", name: "ID: ' . $value_item->term_id . ( ( strlen( $value_item_info->name ) > 0 ) ? ' - ' . esc_html__( 'Name', 'amely' ) . ': ' . $value_item_info->name : '' ) . ( strlen( $value_item_info->slug ) > 0 ? ' - ' . esc_html__( 'Slug', 'amely' ) . ': ' . $value_item_info->slug : '' ) . '"},';
                    }
                }
            }

            $output = '<div class="tokeninput">';
            $output .= '<input id="' . $id . '" name="' . $param_name . '" value="' . $value . '" type="text" class="wpb_vc_param_value" />';
            $output .= '</div>';
            $output .= '<script>jQuery("#' . $id . '").tokenInput("' . esc_js( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) . '?action=vc_ajax_search&type=' . urlencode( $type ) . '&get=' . urlencode( $get ) . '&field=' . urlencode( $field ) . '", {
                prePopulate: [' . $pre_populate . '], resultsLimit: ' . $ajax_limit . ', excludeCurrent: true } );</script>';

            return $output;
        }
    }

    new Amely_Ajax_Search();
}
```

Comment: please paste the complete code including hook.

Comment: @dineshkashera Okay i will update my code

Comment: i have updated my code